# Kohana 3: ORM Validation messages

Tags: php, validation, message, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm trying to add validation messages in Kohana 3 (Orm Model).

classes/model/cliente.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Model_Cliente extends ORM {
 protected $_table_name = 'clientes';
 protected $_primary_key = 'id';
 protected $_has_one = array('loja' => array());
 protected $_rules = array(
  'responsavel' => array('not_empty' => array(), 'min_length' => array(3)),
  'email' => array('not_empty' => array(), 'email' => array()),
  'telefone' => array('regex' => array('/^(\(\d{2}\)|\d{2})[ -]?\d{4}[ -]?\d{4}$/'))
 );
}
?>
```

messages/cliente.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

return array(
    'responsavel' => array(
        'not_empty' => 'O nome do responsável não pode ficar em branco.',
        'min_length' => 'O nome do responsável deve conter 3 caracteres ou mais.'
    )
);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [responsavel] => Array ( [0] => not_empty [1] => Array ( ) ) [email] => Array ( [0] => not_empty [1] => Array ( ) ) )
```

I don't get any validation message, just this output above...
Any ideia? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem today.

Solution: validate()->errors('') instead of validate()->errors().

This is with the beta core from https://github.com/samsoir/core/tree/master/classes/kohana but maybe it's the same in 3.08.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `->errors()` without any params means that you need error originals instead of error translations. Result will contain field names and their error description (rule/callback name + params applied). In your example you have `not_empty` rules (without args) on the `responsavel` and `email` fields.

Btw, `->errors('')` and `->errors('validate')` are synonyms.